# Unable to type > character in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I am using the Canadian Multilingual Standard Keyboard, I can't type the greater than character which are the keys AltCar + period. A dialog box shows

There are no custom foldings in the current file.

Removing/changing the shortcut for **Fold selection/ Remove region** in the **Keymap** did not work. I've also tried to add `actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true` to `bin/idea.properties` but I can't apply changes to `idea.properties`.

Comment: The actual shortcut that it is triggered is _Custom Folding..._, which has a default mapping of `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`.`.

Comment: @DidierL thanks for pointing that out !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Slash (Cmd-Alt-Shift-Slash if you're using Mac OS X), select "Registry" from the menu that appears and enable the "actionSystem.force.alt.gr" checkbox in the menu that appears.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Shift-Slash does nothing for me, can you say which menu item this goes to?

Comment: It doesn't go to any menu item. In newer IDEA versions you can select "Registry..." from the "Goto Action" menu (Ctrl-Shift-A)

Answer (score 2):

Go to **File | Settings | Keymap**. On the top of the screen, in a dropdown box you will see that one of the default keymap is selected. You need to make a copy of it. This is important becasue you can't change the default keymaps. To copy it, click on the **Copy** button on the right of the dropdown box and name your new layout however you want.

Now, with your new Keymap selected, search for the "Custom Fo...". Right click on any shortcut that is mapped to either <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to delete it. Hit **OK** and you should be good to go.